# How to process the convex conjugate of a non-smooth function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose I have a convex function $f(x) = \|x\|_1 + \|x\|_2^4/4$, how to get its conjugate function?

When $f(x)$ is differentiable, according to the definition of conjugate function,
$$
f^*(y)=\sup_x[y^Tx-f(x)]
$$
We can obtain optimal $y$ through,
$$
y =\nabla f(x)
$$
and then substitute this back to the definition to get $f^*(y)$.

But in this case, part of $f(x)$ is L1 norm, which is not differential at $x=0$, how to get the conjucate funtion of it?

If I treat it as piecewise function, and consider the case where $x\neq0$, we can obtain:
$$
y = \nabla f(x) = sign(x) + \|x\|_2^2 \cdot x
$$
It seems quite hard to represent $x$ using $y$. Thus, I cannot substitute $x$ back into $f^*(y) = y^T x-f(x)$ to eliminate variable $x$.

So I meet a new problem about how to represent $x$ using $y$?

Comment: In the 1d case I think you can do the same thing, but the derivative now becomes the set $[D_{-}f(x), D_{+}f(x)]$

Comment: Well, but it seems quite hard to represent x using y when consider $x\neq0$

Comment: Perhaps you could try writing $\|x\|_1 = \max_{\|z\|_\infty \le 1} z^T x$? And do some informal interchange of $\sup$ and $\min$ just to see.

Comment: I have not spent much time on this, but a quick calculation gives me $f^*(y) = {3 \over 4} \|y-z\|^{3 \over 4}$, where $z = \operatorname{proj}_\overline{B_\infty(0,1)} y$.